# Unable to run selenium python script over proxychains

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

**Introduction**
I have made a small script using Python3 that opens gecko webdriver and opens a any website. Then I added some other feature like ability to open window many times in loop.

**Error**
The script works when run normally using:

> Python3 run.py

But when the same thing is run using proxychains, I get the error 'Denied'.
All the script logic and error messages below..

**Script - Running**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
time.sleep(delay_time)
driver.close()
```

**Script - Rotations**

```
for x in range(rotations):
        print(f"Session: {x} started")
        run_driver(delay) # function for running driver
```

**Error over proxychains**

```
ProxyChains-3.1 (http://proxychains.sf.net)
Loading useragent file .. 

Session: 0 started
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:46985-<--denied
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:46985-<--denied
|DNS-request| localhost 
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:46985-<--denied
|DNS-request| localhost 
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:46985-<--denied
|DNS-request| localhost 
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:46985-<--denied
|DNS-request| localhost 
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-4.2.2.2:53-<><>-OK
|DNS-response| localhost is 127.0.0.1
|R-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<><>-127.0.0.1:46985-<--denied
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 proxychains python3 run.py --num 1 --delay 1 --ripper 0
```

Any help is appreciated. Thankyou.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  But this is a good first question.